# Which of these ways is correct to find $a$ and $b$ in $a+b=13$ in which they are in the golden ratio?

Tags: systems-of-equations, golden-ratio

I have two quantities $a$ and $b$ which satisfy $a+b=13$. I want to find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which, they are in the golden ratio, i.e. $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)$. My question is :

Should I solve $a+b=13$ and $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)$ to find the values?

or I should solve $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)$ and $\frac{a+b}{a}=\frac{13}{a}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)$?

Comment: The fraction in the second choice has an equation in the numerator. That makes no sense. The first choice is exactly what you say you want. By the way, the answer should be close to $5$ and $8$ since $3,5,8$ is a sequence of Fibonacci numbers. If you need integers, use those.

Comment: Can you solve $\dfrac a{13-a}=\frac12(\sqrt5+1)$?  Actually, either alternative should work

Comment: $\frac ab=\frac12(\sqrt5+1)=\varphi$ is one of the equations in the first system

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are right. Both systems work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual let $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$ be the golden ratio. You know (or can easily check) that $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$, so if $a=b\varphi$, then $$a\varphi=b\varphi^2=b\varphi+b=a+b=13\,.$$ Clearly the system

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&b\varphi=a\\
&a\varphi=13
\end{align*}\right.$$

is a very easy one to solve, first for $a$ and then for $b$.

Comment: A downvote without an explanation is unhelpful.